# Find all strings of $w$ that satisfy following equation

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Solve the following string equation on the alphabet $A = \{1, 0\}$ and find all $w$'s:

$w011 = 011w$

Answer (score 0):

| $w_0$ | $w_1$ | $w_2$ | $w_3$ | $w_4$ | ... | $w_{n-2}$ | $w_{n-1}$ | $w_{n}$ | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | $w_0$ | $w_1$ | ... | $w_{n-5}$ | $w_{n-4}$ | $w_{n-3}$ | $w_{n-2}$ | $w_{n-1}$ | $w_{n}$ |

We can see that $w_0$ has to be equal to $w_3$, $w_6$... Recursively $n-2$ has to be divisible by 3, because only $w_0 = 0$ from set {$w_0$, $w_1$, $w_2$}. So all strings are of form $(011)*$.

So we have $w=\emptyset$, $w = 011$, $w=011011$...